# Android app hang during updating

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask

This is my code. Why this app during updating is hanging. Is it wrong implement async? 
In this app I have one list. Content of this list is response body from my server. I use OkHttpClient library

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


private MyContinousAsyncTask myContinouslyRunningAsyncTask;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
    StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
    myContinouslyRunningAsyncTask = new MyContinousAsyncTask();
    myContinouslyRunningAsyncTask.execute("execute");
}

String run(String url) throws IOException {
    OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();
    Request request = new Request.Builder()
            .url(url)
            .build();

    Response response = client.newCall(request).execute();
    return response.body().string();
}

private void refresh() throws IOException {
    final ListView listview = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lvChat);
    String url = "???"; //hidden


    String code = run(url);

    String[] values = code.split("<break>");

    final ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
    for (int i = 0; i < values.length; ++i) {
        list.add(values[i]);
    }
    // list.add(code);
    final StableArrayAdapter adapter = new StableArrayAdapter(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, list);
    listview.setAdapter(adapter);

}
```

Adapter Class:

```
private class StableArrayAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {

    HashMap<String, Integer> mIdMap = new HashMap<String, Integer>();

    public StableArrayAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId,
                              List<String> objects) {
        super(context, textViewResourceId, objects);
        for (int i = 0; i < objects.size(); ++i) {
            mIdMap.put(objects.get(i), i);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        String item = getItem(position);
        return mIdMap.get(item);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean hasStableIds() {
        return true;
    }

}
```

AsyncTask Class:

```
public class MyContinousAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
    Timer timer;
    TimerTask timerTask;

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        timer = new Timer();
        timerTask = new TimerTask() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        try {
                            refresh();
                        } catch (IOException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
        };
        timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(timerTask, 100, 5000);
        return "execute";
    }

}
}
```

Please help